# In Jsoup how to change/split nodes during iteration

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I am having html file with document. During parsing i will split textnode which causes Concurrent modification error.

> ```
> private void processInContent(Node ele) {
>         String text = "";        
>         for (Node child : ele.childNodes()) {            
>             Node parentNode = child.parentNode();
>             if (child instanceof TextNode && !("a").equalsIgnoreCase(parentNode.nodeName())) {
>                 TextNode childText = (TextNode) child;
>                 text = childText.text();
>                 System.out.println(text);
>                 Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
>                 while (m.find()) {
>                     String matched = null;
>                     boolean url = false;
>                     if (m.group(2) != null) {
>                         matched = m.group(6);
>
>                     } else {
>                         break;
>                     }
>                     text = childText.text();
>                     TextNode replaceNode = childText.splitText(text.indexOf(matched));
>                     TextNode lastNode = replaceNode.splitText(matched.length());                    
>                     Element anchorEle = ele.ownerDocument().createElement("a");
>                     anchorEle.attr("href", "mailto:" + matched);
>
>                     anchorEle.attr("target", "_blank");
>                     anchorEle.text(matched);
>                     replaceNode.replaceWith(anchorEle);                    
>                     childText = lastNode;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Sample Content

```
 <div id="abc"><br>---- The email address is abc@abc.com</b> contains abc
 domain email address <br></div>
```

I want to add anchor tag for email address which results in below exception

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1008)
        at JSOUPParse.processInContent(JSOUPParse.java:253)
        at JSOUPParse.main(JSOUPParse.java:318)
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused because you are adding nodes to `Node ele` while traversing them. This is illegal and that is the meaning of the `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

You can store the Nodes you want to process in the loop `for (Node child : ele.childNodes())` and after that you can do the modifications in another loop.

```
private void processInContent(Node ele) {
    String text = "";        

    ArrayList<Node> toReplace = new ArrayList<Node>();
    for (Node child : ele.childNodes()) {            
        Node parentNode = child.parentNode();
        if (child instanceof TextNode && !("a").equalsIgnoreCase(parentNode.nodeName())) {
            toReplace.add(child);
        }
    }
    for (Node child : toReplace){
        TextNode childText = (TextNode) child;
        text = childText.text();
        Matcher m = pattern .matcher(text);
        while (m.find()) {
            // more code .........
            Element anchorEle = ele.ownerDocument().createElement("a");
            // more code .........
        }
    }
}
```

This code won't throw `ConcurrentModificationException`

Hope it helps.